# Is it possible to do session related unit test on CakePHP by command line?

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, cakephp

I want to do unit testing about certain controller.
The test uses session on command line.
For example,below.

```
<?php
    App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');
    App::import('Component', 'Session');

    class UsersControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

        public $fixtures = array(
            'app.user',
        );
        public function testSession() {
            $Session =& new SessionComponent(new ComponentCollection());
            $Session->write('testVar','some value');
            $this->assertEquals('some value',$Session->read('testVar'));
        }
    }
```

This test passes on web browser in `http://localhost/test.php`.
On the command line, I run this command.

```
cake test app Controller/UsersController --stderr
```

But the test fails. CUI response shows below

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /path/to/cake/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
    F    

Time: 322 ms, Memory: 9.25Mb    

There was 1 failure:    

1) UsersControllerTest::testSession
Failed asserting that false matches expected 'some value'.    

/path/to/cake/app/Test/Case/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php:13
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php:82
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestRunner.php:60
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/TestShell.php:273
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Command/TestShell.php:258
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php:440
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:207
/path/to/cake/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:66    

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I think it is possible to do session related test by command line if "stderr" option is added to the command, because [the official document](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-your-first-test-case) says

```
If you are running tests that interact with the session it’s generally a good idea to use the --stderr option. This will fix issues with tests failing because of headers_sent warnings.
```

and

```
Running tests that use sessions
When running tests on the command line that use sessions you’ll need to include the --stderr flag. Failing to do so will cause sessions to not work. PHPUnit outputs test progress to stdout by default, this causes PHP to assume that headers have been sent which prevents sessions from starting. By switching PHPUnit to output on stderr, this issue is avoided.
```

If possible, I don't want use mock of session.
Actually, is it possible to do session related testing by command line? Have I mistaken something?

I use 
 CakePHP 2.4.7
 PHP 5.5.9
 OS X 10.8.5

Comment: AD7six, Thanks for your reply. Off course, my real testing is not like that. It just to illustrate "the problem".
In brief, I wonder if it is possible to do a test which uses session by command line without mocking, as official document says. If the test such as above one can be passed by command line, it satisfy my purpose.

Comment: In principle that aught to work. If you `debug($_SESSION); die;` after write you'll probably find that there's no problem writing - I suspect you're being affected by [this change](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/2693) - You need to identify why it doesn't work (by debugging the CakeSession class) to know what's wrong in your case.

Comment: Thanks. `debug($_SESSION); die;`showed `array()` which means empty array. For the discussed change, I tried updating cakephp to 2.5. But nothing changed. Though now I don't have a command-line debugging environment, I will try debugging the process as you said.
And I suspect my local environment such as php.ini setting.